# Limit: Quotient of two functions

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Suppose that we know that the following limit is defined:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=l$$
Where $g,f : \mathbb{N} \to\mathbb{R}$.

And, also, we are aware of the following:

$\exists \:  c \in \mathbb{R},\: n_0 \in \mathbb{N}:
f(n)\le c\cdot g(n) \ \forall \ n \ge n_0  $

$\exists \:  c' \in \mathbb{R},\: n_0' \in \mathbb{N}:
f(n) \ge c'\cdot g(n) \ \forall \ n \ge n_0'  $

I have to prove that: $ 0 < l < \infty$

Mi first approach was to try and use the inequalities above to reach an expression like $|\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}-l|<\epsilon$ and thus proving the exercise with the definition of a limit. But that got me nowhere, and then I realized the following:
$c'\cdot g(n) \le f(n)\le c\cdot g(n) \iff c' \le \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\le c$

Now, when $n \to \infty$, then: $c' \le l \le c \implies 0 < l < \infty $.

That's where my question enters:
Is this proof correct, would I need to add something else? Is there another way to do it?
Maybe using the definition of a limit?

Thanks! :)

Edit: $c,c' \in \mathbb{R_{>0}}$

Edit (2) : $g,f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R_{>0}}$

Comment: Note that $g(n)$ can be negative...So the inequality is reversed in this case. Since $f,g: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb {R}$

Comment: Sorry! They're supposed to be from N to positive R, my bad. I added a edit, thanks for pointing it out :) !

Comment: Ok no problem .......

Answer (score 1):

If $c'>0$, not only $c' \in \mathbb{R}$, then proof is correct: you know limit exists for $a_n=\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ and $c' \leqslant a_n \leqslant c$, so $c' \leqslant \lim a_n \leqslant c$.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, c and c' are real positive numbers, I forgot to add that in the original post, there's and edit now.